# How to show the waiter spinner in shiny renderPrint() output?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show `waiter` in shiny `renderPrint()` output, however, the default `rederPrint()` output is too narrow that the waiter spinner cannot be fully displayed.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(waiter)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      waiter::use_waiter(),
      column(width = 4,
             sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
             actionButton("go", "go", class = "btn-warning")
             ),
     column(width = 8,
            textOutput("text"),
            )
     )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    observeEvent(input$go, {
      w <- waiter::Waiter$new(id = "text")
      w$show()
      Sys.sleep(3) 
      on.exit({w$hide()})
      output$text <- renderPrint({
        cat(paste0(input$slider, " selected."))
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a `hight` parameter to the `textOutput` via `tagAppendAttributes`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(waiter)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      waiter::use_waiter(),
      column(width = 4,
             sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
             actionButton("go", "go", class = "btn-warning")
      ),
      column(width = 8, tagAppendAttributes(textOutput("text"), style = "height:50px;"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    w <- waiter::Waiter$new(id = "text")
    w$show()
    Sys.sleep(3) 
    on.exit({w$hide()})
    cat(paste0(input$slider, " selected."))
  }) |> bindEvent(input$go)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: please avoid nesting `renderXXX` functions.